# Round max of the axis / barplot and hist

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a large quantity of graphs to produce and I would like to get an automatized script to produce most of them.

I use barplot and hit in R. 
With the graphic parameters breaks,xaxp/yaxp and xlim/ylim, I would like to have automatic values:

- for breaks: I want breaks to divide the X-axis every 100 (one bar for 0-100, the other one for 100-200, etc.)
- xaxp and ylim: I would like to have the max value rounded at the next hundreds, and the axis labels every 100 with labels and ticks.
- xlim/ylim: I am searching how to get the max value rounded at the next 5 multiples, and I want to have labels and ticks every 5.

Edit: I found the solution:

```
ry<-round(max(g4$density),digit=-1)
ry
t<-pretty((table$col1), max(table$col1)/500)
t
plot(g4,freq=F, axe=F, col=c("gray"), main="", xlab=NA , ylab=NA, ylim=c(0,ry),xlim=c(0,max(t)))
plot(g4,freq=F, axe=F, col=c("gray"), main="", xlab=NA , ylab=NA, ylim=c(0,ry),xlim=c(0,max(t)))
axis(1,xaxp=c(0,max(t),max(t)/500), line=-0.7, xlim=c(0,t))
axis(2,yaxp=c(0,ry,ry/5), line=-0.9, las=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
ry<-round(max(g4$density),digit=-1) ry 
t<-pretty((table$col1), max(table$col1)/500) 
t 
plot(g4,freq=F, axe=F, col=c("gray"), main="", xlab=NA , ylab=NA, ylim=c(0,ry),xlim=c(0,max(t)))

plot(g4,freq=F, axe=F, col=c("gray"), main="", xlab=NA , ylab=NA, ylim=c(0,ry),xlim=c(0,max(t))) 

axis(1,xaxp=c(0,max(t),max(t)/500), line=-0.7, xlim=c(0,t)) 
axis(2,yaxp=c(0,ry,ry/5), line=-0.9, las=2)
```